# Where can I see a list of all the .NET classes in one place?

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3

I'm used to ActionScript 3, which has [great documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/). In one panel you can see a list of packages along with pages for language elements, and in another panel you can see a list of classes, and it gives you the option of seeing every class across every package in one big scrollable list. It's the entire language at your fingertips. I may have been spoiled by this convenience, because I keep looking for something like that as I learn other languages like SQL, C++, and C#.

The Microsoft website has [documentation for all the .NET classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx), but you need to either know which namespace to look in or use the search option. Is there anywhere I can see the entire language laid out for something like C# the same way I can see it with ActionScript? I mean all the keywords and operators and classes all in one place. Thanks in advance!

Comment: .Net framwork is much bigger than Actionscript, this is why you may not find what you are looking for.

Comment: Check out this Microsoft Reference, not quite the same as ActionScript but maybe it can be used in conjunction with the documentation: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Standard CLI libraries are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI) and some other libraries are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_libraries_and_frameworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search the web for ".NET Framework [Common Namespaces and Types Poster](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19341)."  That will probably be as close as you'll come.  The link above is for .NET Framework 3.5 because I couldn't find a working link for 4.0+.

But, to be honest, the .NET Framework is so huge those posters aren't of much help.  You're probably better off trying to find a resource for the particular area of development you're interested in (ie. Web development, Mobile apps, Console apps, etc.) and see if someone has put something together that targets that area.  Is there an area you're interested in that maybe we could use to point you in the right direction?

As for keywords and operators, you might look at the [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) page rather than the pages about the .NET Framework itself.

**Update:**
Here are a few links for unofficial sources of posters and such from the various framework versions (though they seem to have dead links for .NET 4+ also)

- [.NET Framework 4 and Extensions](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/NETFX4-Poster.pdf)
- [.NET Framework posters with Namespaces & Types](https://itcherokee.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/net-framework-posters-with-namespaces-types/)
- [Collection of .NET Framework and Visual Studio Posters](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/collection-of-net-framework-and-visual.html)

Comment: Thank you, these are great resources, and I made sure to bookmark the C# Reference page. The posters are better than nothing, sure, but the problem is that I need to be able to click things to view more detailed information about them. I appreciate that the scale of the .NET Framework is restrictive, but I'd think what I'm looking for could at least be managed for the standard libraries that Shannon mentioned.

I seem to have a habit of asking unanswerable questions, so I should probably mark this as the answer once I give other people a chance to answer too.

Comment: Glad to help.  I'd be surprised if you find much more than MSDN or the referencesource.microsoft.com link @Bassie mentioned (_didn't know about that one - thanks_), but please post back if you do.  I understand the need for something better than MSDN.  I just know it would be a nightmare for anyone other than MS to maintain.  The only people I see investing this kind of time are maybe Linux users who don't want to depend on MS (and they probably wouldn't want to use .NET anyway).  But, even the [mono project documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/) page just links to MSDN.